# How to get my location againts a Beacon on a floor Plan

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, location, android-ibeacon

Recently i have a requirement in which i need to put some beacons at different place on a Floor. I've to get notification on the basis of beacons devices once i enter from main door and i have to display path from my current position to beacons on a Floor plan (probably an image and need to draw a path). How can i achieve my current position and direction from placed Beacons. At the same time i have one more query about beacons that how much these devices are accurate in performance and locating regions.

Am i missing something. If anybody have gone through this topic please help me so i can look forward in this solution.

Comment: did you find any solution yet ?

Comment: Beacons are never accurate so you have to use Trigonometry Triangle solution. You should use three beacons as three coordinates and find out your position and you have to put it on path on the near by position from the found position.